# How to fix 'Unable to lookup in current state: Shutdown' error

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, ios-simulator, react-native-ios

I'm new in macOs and whenever I try to run my app I get this error

> hg@0.0.1 ios
> react-native run-ios

```
info Found Xcode workspace "hg.xcworkspace"
info Launching iPhone 12 (iOS 14.4)
info Building (using "xcodebuild -workspace hg.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme hg -destination id=70F98FFE-B73E-4E70-9856-4FB635F7B6BD")
success Successfully built the app
info Installing "/Users/mu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/hg-dalmerybpbcohpexdotdxpbbxxeh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/hg.app"
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError, code=405):
Unable to lookup in current state: Shutdown
info Launching "org.reactjs.native.example.hg"
error Failed to launch the app on simulator, An error was encountered processing the command (domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError, code=405):
Unable to lookup in current state: Shutdown
```

As i mentioned earlier I'm fairly new to macOS and whenever I try to run my project I'm getting this error.I have tried deleting and creating a new project but same error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

This problem still arises from time to time due to the Xcode caches. You need to clear out the DerivedData folder for the simulator to launch again.

Navigate to >YOUR_USER_FOLDER>/Library/Developer/Xcode and delete the DerivedData folder. That should be enough to resolve the problem but you can also clean the project in Xcode as a final step as well before trying to build again.